# LDAP troubleshooting

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-sbs-2011

We have a Windows SBS 2011 which sometimes responds slowly to access requests. I'm troubleshooting performance issues fro a while, and now i want to know if there is any problem with the AD, LDAP requeests.

I've been tracking LDAP performance in perfmon in the last 12 hours:

```
LDAP Bind time: min: 0 - max: 16 avg: 0,4
LDAP client sessions: 44-61 avg: 51
LDAP Searches/sec: 0,5-7,4 avg: 2,2
```

I used the following link as a guide, but more DRA counters are not working.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961942.aspx

Here is a "net stats server" reply:

```
Statistics since 24/08/2015 19:48:53 p.m.

Sessions accepted                  10
Sessions timed-out                 0
Sessions errored-out               92

Kilobytes sent                     38524400
Kilobytes received                 130191

Mean response time (msec)          0

System errors                      0
Permission violations              197737
Password violations                0

Files accessed                     3500479
Communication devices accessed     0
Print jobs spooled                 0

Times buffers exhausted

  Big buffers                      0
  Request buffers                  0

The command completed successfully.
```

Do you have any ideas how could i tune up the system? I'm worried about the errored out sessions, and the permission violations too.

Comment: Have you recorded OS' overall performance? If the box doesn't play well, LDAP will not play well also (:

Comment: Yes, I'm in the middle of a performance check. The server has serious memory handling problems (due to SQL and Exchange) and it still uses the HDD too much, but it has now plenty memory and the processor time. I think i shouldn't see this kind of errors anyway.

Comment: Sorry: ...The server **had** serious memory handling problems...